# Use a linear approximation to estimate the number $64.07^{2/3}$

Tags: calculus, optimization, approximation

That's all they give you. I tried putting it into the linear approximation equation of:

$$
f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)
$$

but I get almost the same value as $64.07^{2/3}$, which is around $16.0116$. Just not sure how else to go about doing this problem. Thanks.

Comment: So, the approximation is very good. Your solution is correct.

Comment: If you used $a=64$ and $f(x)=x^{2/3}$ then you did it right. The linear approximation should be quite near the true value since $x-a=0.07$ is small (and $f'$ is not especially large).

Answer (score 1):

Consider function $f(x)=x^{2/3}$ and establish, from definitions, Taylor series at $x=64$ since $64^{2/3}=16$.

You will get for first order (linear approximation)  $$f(x)=16+\frac{x-64}{6}+O\left((x-64)^2\right)$$ from which $x=\frac{9607}{600}\approx 16.01166667 $. **This is exactly what you did.**

For more accuracy, you could use the second order expansion (quadratic approximation) would be   $$f(x)=16+\frac{x-64}{6}-\frac{(x-64)^2}{2304}+O\left((x-64)^3\right)$$ from which $x=\frac{368908751}{23040000}\approx 16.01166454$

For ten significant digits, the exact solution is $\approx 16.01166454$.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent formula
for $x^a$
is
$(1+x)^a
\approx 1+ax
$ 
for small $x$.

Therefore,
for small $v$,
$(u^{a}+v)^{1/a}
=u(1+\frac{v}{u^a})^{1/a}
\approx u(1+\frac{v}{au^a})
= u+\frac{uv}{au^a}
= u+\frac{u^{1-a}v}{a}
$.

In this case,
$a = \frac32$,
so
$(u^{3/2}+v)^{2/3}
\approx u+\frac{u^{-1/2}v}{\frac32}
=u+\frac{2v}{3\sqrt{u}}
$.

If $u=16$
and $v = .07$,
this gives
$16+\frac{.14}{12}
=16.01166...
$.